# JavaScript Button which take me to document before i click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have problem with my small project I learning javascript and I made script that counts to us square of number which you write.

```js
var checkIt = function(){
 var theNumber = Number(prompt("Podaj liczbe", ""));
if (!isNaN(theNumber)) {
 document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = ("Twoja liczba jest pierwiastkiem kwadratowym liczby "+ theNumber * theNumber);
} else {
 document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = ("Hej to miała być liczba!<button class = 'btn btn-default'>Reset</button> ");

}
};
```

```css
body {

}
nav ul li {
 display: inline;
}
nav ul li a {
 border: 5px solid green;
 color: black;
 background-color: white;
 font-size: 25px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover {
 background-color: green;
 color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <nav>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Start</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Start</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Start</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
 <section class="container">
  <p>Hello Wordl i'm learning JavaScript right now :)</p>
  <div id="test">
   <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="checkIt()">Sprawdź się :p</button>
  </div>
 </section>
```

This a code and now I want to add a button that take us to place before we click button to count a square. I hope you understand me

Comment: Do you mean that you want a button that scoll the page to the position of the button that make the square number ?

Comment: No i want button that reset result of my script to state before i click button "Sprawdź się :p". When i click it prompt me and i must to write a number and then it show a squre of that number and i want to add button that reset that and let me to write another number :)

Comment: You just need to reload the page. Check my answer below @BartekMikołajczuk

Comment: its fine but I cannot just hmm refresh only div where I have my button? but thanks for help :)

Comment: Yes you can. I will edit my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You essentially need to reload the page.
Here try this,

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" onClick="document.location.reload(true)">Start</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

EDIT

Use this function to reset your html to initial state

```
var reset = function(){
 document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = ('<div id="test"><button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="checkIt()">Sprawdź się :p</button></div>');      
}


<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" onClick="reset()">Start</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```